# How do I find and store dynamically loaded elements with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the usernames from the "Followers" button list on [this](https://foundation.app/@Snowden) profile, using Python Selenium. I am not able to do this for 2 reasons:

1. I cant scroll on the list by using `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` because the list has 2 scrollbars (I don't know why it has 2). If I try to scroll it scrolls the profile page and not the actual list.
2. Even if I manage to scroll the list, how am I supposed to store the usernames? The users are dynamically loaded and for some reason the class id looks like this `class='st--c-PJLV st--c-dhzjXW st--c-edagZx'`

I've tried several ways of solving this but I'm not able to achieve the result I want, any help is appreciated. Here are some code snippets I *tried* to use but instead got an error:

```
scrollElem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='st--c-PJLV st--c-dhzjXW st--c- 
edagZx']/a")
followernumber = 2000
scrollElem[len(scrollElem)-1].location_once_scrolled_into_view
for i in range(0,followernumber):
    new = len(scrollElem)+i
    newname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='st--c-PJLV st--c-dhzjXWstedagZx']/a)[%i]"%new)
    print(newname.text, i)
    newname.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    time.sleep(1)
```

Got the error:`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@class='st--c-PJLV st--c-dhzjXW st--c-edagZx']/a)[47]"}`

I also tried scrolling at the bottom of the list using this algorithm and store the elements while they load but that didn't work either:

```
def scrollDown():
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

The algorithm scrolled the profile page and not the list of followers

I would appreciate any help as I'm new to web-scraping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using requests module to get all the follower names of that profile:

```
import requests

link = 'https://hasura2.foundation.app/v1/graphql'
payload = {"query":"query userFollowersQuery($publicKey: String!, $currentUserPublicKey: String!, $offset: Int!, $limit: Int!) {\n  follows: follow(\n    where: {followedUser: {_eq: $publicKey}, isFollowing: {_eq: true}}\n    offset: $offset\n    limit: $limit\n  ) {\n    id\n    user: userByFollowingUser {\n      name\n      username\n      profileImageUrl\n      userIndex\n      publicKey\n      follows(where: {user: {_eq: $currentUserPublicKey}, isFollowing: {_eq: true}}) {\n        createdAt\n        isFollowing\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":{"currentUserPublicKey":"","publicKey":"0xF74d1224931AFa9cf12D06092c1eb1818D1E255C","offset":0,"limit":48},"operationName":"userFollowersQuery"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    
    while True:
        resp = s.post(link,json=payload)
        if not resp.json()['data']['follows']:break
        for item in resp.json()['data']['follows']:
            print(item['user']['username'])

        payload['variables']['offset']+=48
```

Comment: You are amazing! thank you so much this works great! Didn't know about hasura! Could you lead me to more articles about it and web-scraping using requests? Again thank you so much!

Comment: By the way how did you know the site used hasura?

Comment: Navigate to the url in your post, open chrome dev tool using `F12`, find and press `Network` tab, then `All` tab. Now, reload the page. You should see different type of urls in it's left pane. When you click on any of the urls, you will see all details in it's right pane. This is where I found the url that I used in my answer.

Comment: Do you know I get the publicKey from a profile using requests?